# Classification techniques for continuous arrays as inputs and scalar categorical variable as output

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Suppose for a given data set: T’s and Y’s are arrays with T = [0 1 2 3 5 6 7] Y= [4 7 9 3 6 1] So at T=0, Y=4 and so on Z = [Red] with just one element in Z. T and Y are continuous inputs. Z discrete (can be either red or yellow).

Another given set: T = [1 3 4 9 3] Y= [4 9 2 1 6] Z=[Yellow]

Suppose I have many similar sets, what classification techniques can I use to explore relations which take T and Y as continuous array inputs and outputs categorical Z of single element?

I am a bit confused as the inputs themselves are arrays whereas the output is just a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the output of a model into classification of categorical output is itself just a function that is placed at the end the model's raw output. A pretty neat little "trick" that a lot of people who are learning or just playing around may not notice.

Machine Learning boils down to finding ways to represent your data such that a Machine can read it, otherwise how can it learn? This means it needs to be in numbers.

Using your case, you model will be told that the two input features are T and Y, already numbers, great! But the output is a categorical value, so we need to adjust what the machine thinks these are. Since we have two options, we can say `Red=0`, and `Yellow=1`.

There you go, now your model knows how to spit out the result, you would train it using these adjustments, and when the model spits out an answer of `1`, you then add an extra function at the end that automatically knows that `Yellow=1`, the model doesn't have to know.

In practice, it actually should return *2 numbers*. What is essentially a prediction for the likelihood of each of the colours that would add to 1. So the output of the model would be `[0.25,0.75]`, and then we can say the model was more confident that it was Yellow, so we take that as the prediction.

By doing it this way, you've boiled everything down to numbers, and so the technique is up to you. In reality, the data distributions and the type of task (here it is a binary classification task, because only 2 output options) would affect which techniques are going to be the most affective or practical.

Comment: Thanks! So in such cases it seems like the training data set will have arrays of arrays. Scikit cannot seem to handle such inputs, for example:
[1,2,3,4],[5,4,3,1],[red]
[5,7,4,8],[5,2,3 9],[yellow]
…..
Could you suggest any ml Python package which could work with such inputs?

Comment: `SciKit` is great for this! You just need to concatenate those two arrays because you just have two inputs to training, features and labels. So, `[1,2,3,4],[5,4,3,1]` becomes `[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,1]`. [See here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) for how to properly generate the encoding for categorical values.

Comment: Quick question: for the first set [1,2,3,4],[5,4,3,1],[red] with name, age and color respectively, if say at name=0 age =5, name=2 age=4, name=3 age =3 with elemtns in the name array corresponding to the ones in the age array, will concatenating followed by ml_training work? Asking from the perspective that with concatenation will the information that name=1 age=5 etc. be lost or the ml model be able to make predictions nonetheless. I am a bit new to all this. Maybe a very basic question.

Comment: No, it's a good question, it isn't lost because the model learns solely based on the _position_, not the "name" of the variable. So your array would be defined generally as `[n_1, n_2, n_3, a_1, a_2, a_3]` where `n` and `a` are name and age. It becomes important to keep the _order_ consistent because the model just uses the positions to learn and create the weights (it'll learn the relationship between features). So for the next row, make sure the order is the same and you won't have lost any information. For completeness, equally valid is to have `[n_1, a_1, n_2, a_2, ...] `.